# What would be the appropriate way to use a delegate protocol from 2 views?

Tags: iphone, delegates

I have a view controller, which uses a delegate protocol in order to pass back an array of strings. I now have another view controller, which I'd like to use the same protocol, but I've I use it I get a warning in Xcode `Duplicate protocol definition of 'SearchDetailsDelegate' is ignored`.

I need these two views to pass back an array for the parent view controller to parse. What would be a more appropriate way of achieve what I need to do here? Would key value observing be the way to go here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the protocol in a separate .h file (new file of objective c protocol)  and then include it in the required view controllers.Redefining the same protocol in two different view controllers is not recommended as it has been in your case

Comment: Really hard to choose between these two answers. I've picked this one as it more appropriately reflected the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You have few options:

1. rename your protocols to be different.
2. create an external protocol and adopt that protocol on each view
3. Add a property to your view called ParentController with a type of it's parent.

   @property (strong,nonatomic) ParentViewController *ParentController;

**(synthesise that off course)**

Then, in your viewController, when you instantiate  the view assign the viewController as the parent

```
YourView *childView  = [[YourView alloc]init];
childView.parentController = self;
```

Now you can add a method **in your viewController** that can receive the strings array

```
-(void)setStringsArray:(NSArray*)arr{
     //do what ever you need with the array
     //don't forget to add this method to your .h file so it will be visible
}
```

Lastly send the strings array from the view:
     [self.parentController setStringsArray:yourArray];

**BTW**
  if you want to know what view send the array you can:

```
-(void)setStringsArray:(NSArray*)arr fromView:(UIView*)senderView{
     //do what ever you need with the array
     //don't forget to add this method to your .h file so it will be visible
}
```

and use

```
    [self.parentController setStringsArray:yourArray fromView:self];
```

**BTW 2**
 an other option will be to use notifications.

Comment: Some great options here. If I were to create an external protocol, do I just create a new NSObject file and move my protocol to there? Then do I just `#import "MyProtocolDefinition.h"` and then `@property (nonatomic, retain) id <SearchDetailsDelegate> delegate;` in my child view controller?

Comment: Make sure u also write @protocol MyProtocolName above the interface in the .h file of the class which conforms that protocol